# Using own video player for youtube, dailymotion,vimeo etc

Tags: php, flash, actionscript

I have my own video player, I've bought it from activeden. And im going to use youtube, dailymotion, video api with php. But i want to use my own video player. How can i do that? It takes list from a xml files like this;

```
<video_item> 
<hd_video_path>.flv</hd_video_path>
<sd_video_path>.flv</sd_video_path>
<video_title>....</video_title>
<video_description>...</video_description>
</video_item>
```

Comment: read the doc for the video player you payed for would be a start...

Comment: i already did that. I have to put video's flv url but i have only video id.

Comment: Use your magic Youtube API then (I'm not aware that such a thing exists, nor that they would let you hotlink video data), get the url for the video id, then write your xml file. Sounds easy. Which part of that does your question resolve around?

Answer (score 0):

You should write a script(PHP/.NET or whatever) that pulls in the correct video url for the videos you want to put in your player and assembles your playlist based on those.